# Derivatives of functions with inputs and outputs in $\mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times \cdots \times m_k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose I have a function
$$f:\mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times \cdots \times m_k} \to 
    \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times \cdots \times n_l}.$$
I am looking for a way to reference the "gradient" or matrices of derivatives. I was thinking there is a matrix of partial derivatives for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times \cdots \times m_k}$,
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{i_1, \dots, i_l, j_1, \dots,j_k}
    = \frac{\partial f_{i_1, \dots, i_l}}{\partial x_{j_1, \dots,j_k}}.$$
Then I have a matrix$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times \cdots \times n_l \times m_1 \times \cdots \times m_k}.$

This matrix seems consistent with the idea of a gradient for a function with a single output. Is this just called the gradient? Can I use these derivative matrices for chain rule and what not?

For example let $g: \mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times \cdots \times m_k} \to \mathbb{R}^{p_1 \times \cdots \times p_q}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^{p_1 \times \cdots \times p_q} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times \cdots \times n_l}$ be functions such that $f = h \circ g.$ Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}.$ Is there a notion of multiplication for those last two? If they are two dimensional it is matrix multiplication. But in this case $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ has $k + q$ dimensions, and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}$ has $q + l$ dimensions.

In matrix multiplication, usually you have the middle dimension disappear, for example $[3 \times 2][2 \times 6] \equiv [3 \times 6]$. If I reversed the first set, $i_1, \dots, i_l$ the indices on my first "gradient" equation, I was thinking I could get similar "canceling out the middle" behavior. For example,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &\equiv [n_l \times \cdots n_1 \times p_1 \cdots \times p_q][p_q \times \cdots p_1 \times m_1 \times \cdots m_k] \\
&\equiv [n_l \times \cdots n_1 \times m_1 \times \cdots m_k].
\end{align*}$$

Anyway, I am looking for ideas of where I can look for references to ideas like the above? In most applications I usually see people flatten higher dimensional objections into vectors, so that you just get a matrix, but it seems unnecessary to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret $\mathbb{R}^{m_1\times\ldots\times m_k }$ as $\mathbb{R}^{m_1\cdot\ldots\cdot m_k}$, so instead of a "matrix" in $\mathbb{R}^{m_1\times\ldots\times m_k }$ you have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m_1\cdot\ldots\cdot m_k}$. This is possible because these spaces are isomorphic, so you can treat everything as ordinary vectors.

If you are only concerned about derivatives, it's possible to avoid working with coordinates. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function. The derivative of $f$ in $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map $Df(x):\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x+h) = f(x) + Df(x)\cdot h + r(h)$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$, where the function $r$ satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|r(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$.

Once you find this relation, you have the derivative $Df(x)$ (which is a generalization of the gradient). Once you have $Df(x)$, you can start working with bases and then you can go back to the matrix interpretation.